# apache-mod_auth_kerb; kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos; Client didn't delegate us their credential

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am trying to setup Integrated Windows authentication with kerberos using ActiveDirectory in windows server 2008 and everything works well and I am able to get kerberos tickets on successful login. I am facing problem in forwarding this ticket to server where Apache is configured. When forwading ticket KRB5CCNAME is not set in Apache/PHP environment variables.

My kerberos configuration file(krb5.conf)  is

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = DIVAMI.COM
 default_keytab_file = /etc/krb5.keytab
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]
 DIVAMI.COM = {
  kdc = meluha.divami.com:88
  admin_server = meluha.divami.com:749
  default_domain = divami.com
 }

[domain_realm]
meluha.divami.com = DIVAMI.COM
divami.com = DIVAMI.COM
```

Apache mod_auth_kerb configuration file(auth_kerb) is

```
<Location /perfmon>
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Kerberos Login"
  KrbMethodNegotiate On
  KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
  KrbAuthRealms DIVAMI.COM
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf.d/apache.keytab
  KrbSaveCredentials On
  KrbServiceName HTTP/greenplum.divami.com
  require valid-user
  ErrorDocument 404 "No favicon"

</Location>
```

Browser configuration

Firefox

```
Set network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris to greenplum.divami.com.
Set network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris to greenplum.divami.com
```

IE

```
 In Internet Explorer, select Tools > Internet Options.
 In the Local Internet (Advanced) dialog box, enter all relative domain names that will be used on the intranet (e.g. greenplum.divami.com).
```

When I set KrbMethodK5Passwd On,then browser prompt for kerberos username and password on giving valid credentials ticket is generated and it's cached location is set in Apache/PHP environment variable KRB5CCNAME. Using this variable KRB5CCNAME we can use kerberos ticket that is forwaded as credential for authentication.

I am getting following error message when KrbMethodK5Passwd Off.

```
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 10.81.17.156] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1939): [client 10.81.17.156] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1278): [client 10.81.17.156] Acquiring creds for HTTP/greenplum.divami.com
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1691): [client 10.81.17.156] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1707): [client 10.81.17.156] Client didn't delegate us their credential
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1726): [client 10.81.17.156] GSS-API token of length 180 bytes will be sent back
plum.divami.com/perfmon/login.php
[Wed Sep 25 18:48:11 2013] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1691): [client 10.81.17.156] Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API , referer:http://greenplum.divami.com/perfmon/login.php
```

I have no idea whether browser fails in picking kerberos ticket or browser picks the ticket but unable to set cached location in KRB5CCNAME.
please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

check your keytab file

cat apache.keytab

if you see plain text and no weird characters, your keytab is not generated properly. Likely something on the AD side.

A proper keytab should look like this,

```
cat httpd.keytab 
.G..COMPANY.LOCALweb01.httpd.[N5�...��f\.Z�GR._x?���.G..COMPANY.LOCALweb01.httpd.[N5�...�=.�.�6w!k�e���.W..COMPANY.LOCALweb01.httpd.[N5�.. ]c��84��w�1Jo�.zH�rDY>�
                                                             ����B.F..COMPANY.LOCAL.HTTtestlogs.[N5�...��f\.Z�GR._x?���.F..COMPANY.LOCAL.HTTtestlogs.[N5�...�=.�.�6w!k�e���.V..
```